# QML Retrieve value of a spinbox used in a TableView cell

Tags: qt, qml, tableview, qspinbox

I have a TableView. The 3rd column called "OrderedAmount" contains a spinbox.

```
TableView {
        id: lw_order
        x: 420
        y: 63
        width: 169
        height: 253
        model: orderModelId

        TableViewColumn
        {
            id: tableorderid
            role: "OrderedID"
            title: "ID"
            width: 10
        }
        TableViewColumn
        {
            role: "OrderedItems"
            title: "Items"
            width: 100
        }
        TableViewColumn
        {
            id: tableamountid
            role: "OrderedAmount"
            title: "Amount"
            width: 50
            delegate: Item {
                        SpinBox {
                            id: tableamountspin
                            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                            minimumValue: 1
                            width: 40
                        }
            }
        }




        ListModel {
            id: orderModelId
        }

    }
```

How can I retrieve the actual value of the SpinBox from each line of the table?

I tried this:

```
for (var index = 0 ; index < lw_order.rowCount; index++)
            {
                order = order + orderModelId.get(index).OrderedID + ";" + orderModelId.get(index).OrderedAmount + ";"
            }
```

Unfortunately, I get only the value of the first column called "OrderedID".

`qml: 1;undefined;4;undefined;`

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is you need to set the `SpinBox` value as `styleData.value` which is the value for the `OrderedAmount` element.

If you do so, then you can get the right value in your function using:

`orderModelId.get(index).OrderedAmount`

Remember you will need to update the model when the `SpinBox` changes. Something like this:

`orderModelId.setProperty(styleData.row, "OrderedAmount", value.toString())`

With these ideas in mind, the code could come out something like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 300

    Button {
        text: "click me"

        function getValues(lw_order, orderModelId) {
            for (var index = 0 ; index < lw_order.rowCount; index++)
            {
                print("row: " + index)
                print("  OrderedID: " + orderModelId.get(index).OrderedID + "; " +
                      " OrderedItems: " + orderModelId.get(index).OrderedItems + "; " +
                      " OrderedAmount: " + orderModelId.get(index).OrderedAmount)
            }
        }

        onClicked: {
            getValues(lw_order, orderModelId)
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: orderModelId
        ListElement {
            OrderedID: "1"
            OrderedItems: "10"
            OrderedAmount: "15"
        }

        ListElement {
            OrderedID: "2"
            OrderedItems: "20"
            OrderedAmount: "25"
        }

        ListElement {
            OrderedID: "3"
            OrderedItems: "30"
            OrderedAmount: "35"
        }
    }

    TableView {
        id: lw_order
        x: 0
        y: 50
        width: 300
        height: 300
        model: orderModelId

        TableViewColumn
        {
            id: tableorderid
            role: "OrderedID"
            title: "ID"
            width: 50
        }
        TableViewColumn
        {
            role: "OrderedItems"
            title: "Items"
            width: 100
        }
        TableViewColumn
        {
            id: tableamountid
            role: "OrderedAmount"
            title: "Amount"
            width: 70
            delegate: Item {
                SpinBox {
                    id: tableamountspin
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    minimumValue: 1
                    width: 70
                    value: styleData.value

                    onValueChanged: {
                        if (focus == true) {
                            console.log("onValueChanged - row: "  + styleData.row + " column: " + styleData.column + " value: " + value)
                            orderModelId.setProperty(styleData.row, "OrderedAmount", value.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.